# How to csplit on tabs?

Tags: regex, csplit

I have a tab delimited file with chunks of data separated by lines of empty fields.  It looks like this:

```
#comment\n
data<TAB>data<TAB>data\n
data<TAB>data<TAB>data\n
<TAB><TAB>\n
#comment\n
#comment 2\n
data<TAB>data<TAB>data\n
data<TAB>data<TAB>data\n
data<TAB>data<TAB>data\n
<TAB><TAB>\n
data<TAB><TAB>\n
```

I'm trying to use csplit to split this file into chunks. It's only creating two files, when there are 23 matches to my pattern:

```
$ grep '^       *$' file.txt  | wc -l
23

$ csplit file.txt '/^   *$/'
875
587453

$ ls
file.txt  xx00  xx01
```

I'm using CTRL-V to enter the tab, '\t' doesn't work for either csplit or grep.  The environment is Bash on Cygwin.  I've examined the file with a hex editor, and it's definitely using UNIX line feeds.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to append '{*}' to the end to get it to break more than once.  Who knew?